# Run Open or Load event when Word VBA form opens

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

I have a MS Word VBA form called frmChooseMacros. I want to execute a subroutine on an Open or Load event for that form before the user interacts with the form.

From [Form.Open event (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.open), I came up with this code as a test and added it to the code window for frmChooseMacros:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    MsgBox "Running open event"
End Sub
```

It never executes when the form loads.

From [Form.Load event (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.load), I also tried the Load event, like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "Running open event"
End Sub
```

I run the form through this sub-routine.

```vb
Sub DocFix_00_RunMultipleMacros()
    frmChooseMacros.Show
End Sub
```

...which executes when a button is clicked on the menu.

This image may provide additional context:
[image: Word VBA IDE]

Comment: I just noticed the links I used are for Access, not Word. I don't know if that matters but that might be the issue.

Comment: There is no `Form_Load` event for MSWord Userforms. Did you just copy/paste event code into a form without adding it to an actual event? When a Userform loads, it runs the `UserForm_Initialize` event. See how at the top the combo boxes says "General" and "Form_Load"? They are supposed to show "Userform" in one and "Initialize" in the other. Play with the combo boxes at the top to see how events are handled. The fact that is says "General" means that it's not an actual event, so that explains why it's not getting triggered.

Comment: Thank you @braX! Your suggestion helped me figure it out. I had forgotten that events were in that second drop-down list, and I was trying to figure out the syntax based on that Microsoft Access VBA documentation. To fix this, I added in a `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` routine and then before my `frmChooseMacros.Show` statement, I added these two statements: `Dim oForm As UserForm` and `Set oForm = New frmChooseMacros`

Answer (score 0):

(Credit goes to @braX for helping me find the answer here.)

For Word, you have to use the `UserForm_Initialize` or `UserForm_Activate` events. There is no Form_Load or Form_Open events for Word.

I was able to solve this by first defining a UserForm object and setting it to my frmChooseMacros user form:

```
Sub DocFix_00_RunMultipleMacros()
    Dim oForm As UserForm
    Set oForm = New frmChooseMacros
    frmChooseMacros.Show
End Sub
```

Then I use the UserForm_Activate event here:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  MsgBox "Form has activated."
End Sub
```